# How can i get just the memory speed from dmidecode?

Tags: linux, grep

I need to get the Speed info, but when i get the output:

```
# sudo dmidecode --type 17 | grep 'Speed:'

Speed: 1333 MHz
Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz
Speed: Unknown
Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
Speed: 1333 MHz
Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz
Speed: Unknown
Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

And i need to get:

```
Speed: 1333 MHz
Speed: Unknown
Speed: 1333 MHz
Speed: Unknown
```

How can i get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `awk`:

```
sudo dmidecode --type 17 | awk '$1 == "Speed:"'
```

With grep, you would need to anchor the pattern at the beginning of the line and take some optional spaces into account:

```
sudo dmidecode --type 17 | grep '^[[:space:]]*Speed:'
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your example, this line should help:

```
sudo dmidecode --type 17 | grep '^Speed:'
```

Because it seems that you just want to fetch the line that starts with `Speed:`

Comment: This doesn't work because `dmidecode` prints spaces in front of `Speed:`